# SOQL: Identify Account records that don't have children

Tags: soql, opportunity, account

Being a newbie in SOQL I'am stuck with a little intricate challenge:
I need to scan through the Account-object to find all records that don't

- have no corresponding records in Opportunity object
- have no corresponding records in FinServ__FinancialAccount__c object

I called them "hanging" Accounts but that may not be the correct term.
Is it possible to do this with one query or should it be implemented as for-loop?
Hope someone can help!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `FinServ__FinancialAccount__c` is a child of Account object.

We need to use the `NOT` & `IN` operator to check for Accounts without Opportunities.

For fetching Accounts not having `Opportunities`, we can use :

```
[SELECT Name FROM Account WHERE ID NOT IN (select AccountId from Opportunity)]
```

Similarly , for `FinServ__FinancialAccount__c` :

```
[SELECT Name FROM Account WHERE ID NOT IN (select Account__c from FinServ__FinancialAccount__c)]
```

Here , `Account__c` is the relationship developer name in `FinServ__FinancialAccount__c` object.

Above queries can be combined as :

```
[SELECT Name FROM Account WHERE ID NOT IN (select AccountId from Opportunity) AND (ID NOT IN (select Account__c from FinServ__FinancialAccount__c))]
```

Comment: While rows queried in semi-joins and anti-joins do not count towards the 50k query row limit, one "gotcha" here is that using `NOT` means that those filters don't help with query selectivity. If OP has more than 200k Accounts, this will probably be an issue (even if the number of "hanging" accounts is less than 50k). The "cost" of the query (since this would almost certainly need a tablescan) could make it an issue at lower numbers of Accounts. Getting the query plan for one of the SObjects in my org (using an anti-join) shows a cost of 2.83 when I have ~21,000 records for that SObject.

Comment: @DerekF : I do appreciate your detailed answer but the question does not give much details about the context. Thank you for the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

In short, no. A single query isn't going to be able to handle this. This particular task is more involved than it sounds.

"Find records that don't have children" is unfortunately not something that SOQL is well-suited to handle. The governor limits that we're subject to (50,000 query rows per "transaction", also 100 queries per transaction) also mean that querying *every* record of a given SObject is usually a non-starter as well.

### The simplest approach: Rollups

One of the simplest ways to work around this issue would be to use some rollup summary fields (specifically, 2 rollups. One for each child SObject. Placed on the `Account` SObject) to count the number of child records. The catch there is that the two SObjects need to have a "Master-Detail" relationship to be able to create a rollup summary field.

In such a scenario, the query would look something like this

```
[SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE ChildRecordCount1__c = 0 AND ChildRecordCount2__c = 0]
```

You *can* create a rollup summary field on Account to count the number of Opportunity records, but it's not clear whether or not this is possible for `FinServ__FinancialAccount__c`. Still, any additional information we can get is helpful.

Another option here is to use the [Declarative Lookup Rollup Summary tool](https://install.salesforce.org/products/dlrs/latest) created by Andrew Fawcett, control was given to the Salesforce "Open Source Commons" project. DLRS allows you to create similar "rollup" fields with only a lookup relationship between the two SObjects (it creates triggers/classes (and tests) for you to acheive that).

### I suspect you'll run into the query row limit, so to handle that...

The natural approach here would be to use [Batch Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_interface.htm).

Using the `Batchable` interface is one of the few ways we have to be able to query more than 50k rows. If you return a "queryLocator" from the `start()` method, it allows you to query up to 50 *million* rows. That's going to be able to handle all but the largest of orgs. I.e. it'll be fine as long as you're not working for a multinational, fortune 500 company.

There is one more trick (ok, technically two more) that we can use here that will reduce the number of rows your query returns. We can query child records using a parent-child subquery (see the [documentation on Using Relationship Queries](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_query_using.htm#sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_query_using)). Since you're only interested in knowing if there is at least 1 child record, you can add `LIMIT 1` to the subquery.

```java
public class MyBatchable implements Database.Batchable<sObject>{
    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
        // Parent-child subqueries use the "child relationship name", which is usually
        //   the plural of the object name and "__r" instead of "__c"
        // You may have to adjust this
        return Database.getQueryLocator(
            'SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM FinServ__FinancialAccounts__r LIMIT 1) FROM Account WHERE Opportunity_Rollup_Count__c = 0'
        );
    }

    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Account> scope){
        List<Account> accountsToUpdate = new List<Account>();
        for(Account testAccount :scope){
            // The "safe" way to handle subquery results is by using a nested loop
            // ...but using "LIMIT 1" in the subquery makes it safe to access the
            //   subquery results directly
            if(testAccount.FinServ__FinancialAccounts__r.size() == 1){
                continue;
            }

            // If we get to this point, then we know this Account has no FinServ__FinancialAccount__c 
            //   records that point to it.
            testAccount.isHanging__c = true;
            accountsToUpdate.add(testAcccount);
        }

        // and then DML to actually perform the update
    }

    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){
    }
```

In this example, I'm assuming that you do have a rollup summary field to count Opportunities. If you don't though, it's pretty easy to just add another parent-child subquery instead of using the `WHERE` clause.

```
'SELECT Id, (...), (SELECT Id FROM Opportunities LIMIT 1) FROM Account`
```

Do note that you'll also need to adjust the `if()` statement in the `execute()` method to also check to see if there are any Opportunities (adding another `if()` below the existing `if()` block would also work) if you add the subquery for Opportunities.